# How to build a string by repeating a string with inserted values from an array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to build a regular expression to search for alternative values populated from an array. I'm sure there is a shorthand way to achieve this.

```
searchValues = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
testValue    = "|(x)"
```

I'm looking for some magic using `testValue` where it is repeated with `searchValues` items replacing `x`, resulting in `"(aa)|(bb)|(cc)"`.

Comment: "(aa)|(bb)|(cc)" could be "(aa|bb|cc)". Then it's a simple `f"({'|'.join(searchValues)})"` (but you might need `re.escape` anyway).

Comment: So you want to make the strings to join together by replacing the `x` in `testValue` with each of the values in `searchValues` (almost)?

Comment: Matthias - not if you are using grouping. That's why I can't use JOIN.

Comment: Scott - Yes, so like JOIN, but with the values going into the inside of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use join on a comprehension to escape all values (in case they contain special characters) and form a pattern with interceding pipes:

```
import re 

searchValues = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
pattern = "|".join(re.escape(v) for v in searchValues)

# 'aa|bb|cc'
```

You don't actually need the parentheses but if you want them to form groups you can add then in the comprehension:

```
pattern = "|".join("("+re.escape(v)+")" for v in searchValues)

# '(aa)|(bb)|(cc)'
```

If you are certain that values don't contain special characters, a shorter expression can be used:

```
pattern = f"({')|('.join(searchValues)})"
```

If your values can potentially contain strings that happend to be a prefix of another value, you'll need to place the longer value before the shorter one.  e.g. `['aab','aa','bb','cc']` instead of `['aa','bb','cc','aab',]`. You can ensure that this is the case by sorting the searchValues on length: `searchValues.sort(key=len,reverse=True)`